# stream and reduction contract

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Going through [this example](https://github.com/RichardWarburton/java-8-lambdas-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/insightfullogic/java8/answers/chapter3/FilterUsingReduce.java)

```
public class FilterUsingReduce {

    public static <I> List<I> filter(Stream<I> stream, Predicate<I> predicate) {
        List<I> initial = new ArrayList<>();
        return stream.reduce(initial,
                             (List<I> acc, I x) -> {
                                if (predicate.test(x)) {
                                    // We are copying data from acc to new list instance. It is very inefficient,
                                    // but contract of Stream.reduce method requires that accumulator function does
                                    // not mutate its arguments.
                                    // Stream.collect method could be used to implement more efficient mutable reduction,
                                    // but this exercise asks to use reduce method explicitly.
                                    List<I> newAcc = new ArrayList<>(acc);
                                    newAcc.add(x);
                                    return newAcc;
                                } else {
                                    return acc;
                                }
                             },
                             FilterUsingReduce::combineLists);
    }

    private static <I> List<I> combineLists(List<I> left, List<I> right) {
        // We are copying left to new list to avoid mutating it. 
        List<I> newLeft = new ArrayList<>(left);
        newLeft.addAll(right);
        return newLeft;
    }

}
```

author stated that the contract for reduce prevents arguments from modyfing. Actually, didn't find anything about it in javadoc. What did he mean?